# How to query and return an integer-type field from single record in MySQL / PHP

Tags: php, mysql

So basically, I'm trying to get the amount of likes that are stored in the DB and then show them using this function.

**In this function I'm trying to extract the value of `post_likes` from the MySQL database.**

```
function like_count($id) {

    $connection = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $database);

    $id = $connection->real_escape_string($id);

    $query = $connection->query("SELECT COUNT(`post_likes`) AS `count` FROM `posts` WHERE `id` = '$id'");

    while ( $row = $query->fetch_object() ) {
            if ( $row->count == 1 ) return $row;
    }
}
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Ask one simple, clear question at a time. You also have a lot of coding convention problems. You need to check the result of every database call, and extract the error if the call failed. Never name variables `blahblah`, `blahblah1`, `blahblah2`, etc. Use placeholders ('?') and bind the parameters separately using `stmt->bind(...)`. *Then* we can help. :-)

Comment: @BaseZen I updated the `$query2` to `$likes_query` as it is a different query. Is this kinda what you meant? (I'm quite new to PHP, so I might not understand it fully)

Comment: Yes but 57 times more important than that is to trim this down to one question. One buggy function at a time. Start with the top function. Explain what you expect the output of the function to be, and what it actually is, and any error messages or crashes along the way. I might ask why you're only returning the row when the "like" count is exactly 1. Presumably you're asking how many likes apply, and there may be many.

Comment: @BaseZen Updated the post again. Hopefully this makes it more clear :)

Comment: Please change this to a meaningful title that would help someone with a similar problem find an answer. Probably you can rework this question to be about COUNT()

Comment: @Elin Updated, a little.

Comment: The irony here is that COUNT() should never have been used. There's not even a need for aliasing `post_likes` to lower-case `count`. See answer.

Comment: @BaseZen True as well. I'm really confused on what to put as the title for this question..

Comment: "How to query and return an integer-type field from single record in MySQL / PHP"? And also suggest removing all the preliminary junk before the code listing and just say you're trying to extract the number of likes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:

```
SELECT COUNT(`post_likes`)
```

with just:

```
SELECT `post_likes`
```

AND, replace:

```
while ( $row = $query->fetch_object() ) {
    if ( $row->count == 1 ) return $row;
}
```

with:

```
return $query->fetch_object()->count
```

Which will return the integer count.

I don't understand the motivation to compare the count to 1. Note there should always be error handling with any database call, but one thing at a time.

I think you also misunderstand the `COUNT` function. The `post_likes` field already has the value you need. The way you wrote the query the first time implied a different structure to the data than you really have.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! There's only one slight problem. It only returns 1 while the `post_likes` in the database are 22.

Comment: Answer updated accordingly. Now we've decoded your actual structure and intent.